C# debugging in Visual Studio
IN my visual studio, I code in C#. When I want to run a different program I can't run. Every time I run another program the compiler runs the first and same program again and again but not the program I want to run. How to overcome this problem?
In my first project in C#, there is a program called 'Program.cs' and it was created by default with the project and it works perfectly. But when I create other programs and run them, they won't run. Compiler runs 'Program.cs' every time.

you probably need to either set the startup-project in VS to the pther proram (btw. not the cs-file, but the csproj-file, where the cs-file is located in), or righ-click that csproj-file and chose Debug->start new instance
